# Meaning and usage of "to be done for"

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage

(Not to be confused with "to be done with *stng*")

I've seen several times the expression "to be done for", not followed by anything.
Here is an example not so far from what I could actually read or hear:

```
- John, the boss wants you to send the client a complete proposal by 6 today.
- Gee... I'm done for.
```

My understanding is that this means "I'm scr**d/ruined", and probably less derogatory than the first. Is this correct, and is this the only usage of this expression?

Comment: Agreed. As in "I'm finished", "The game's up for me".

Comment: Dead, screwed, ruined, etc.  Not "derogatory" per se, nor in any way obscene, but it does indicate an unhappy situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Would any of you like to make an actual answer of this in a way I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, "I'm dead" or "I'm going to be killed."

In nineteenth-century England, the expression "I'll do for him" (no direct object) meant, "I'll murder him." My understanding is that it was considered a fairly coarse, lower-class expression. It may have been in use earlier, but that's the period from which I know it.